# Обработка нажатий нескольких клавиш одновременно

Tags: java, android

Пишу приложение для Android, которое должно управлять "машиной".

Суть в том, что если нажать одновременно 2 кнопки (прям тютелька в тютельку) - обрабатывается нажатие лишь одной клавиши.

Как можно сделать так, чтобы обрабатывались все 4 клавиши? Может, как-то повесить на каждую свой отдельный поток-обработчик?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button ChangeServo, ChangeEngine, ResetServo, ResetEngine;

    ControlArduino arduino = new ControlArduino();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arduino.init_arduino("");
        arduino.KeepConnectAndSend();

        Log.d("MAIN CLASS", "onInitButton");
        ChangeEngine = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ChangeEngine);
        ChangeServo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ChangeServo);
        ResetEngine = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ResetEngine);
        ResetServo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ResetServo);


        ChangeServo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                arduino.ServoRange = "225";
            }
        });

        ChangeEngine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                arduino.EngineRange = "225";
            }
        });

        ResetServo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                arduino.ServoRange = "0";
            }
        });

        ResetEngine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                arduino.EngineRange = "0";
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: используйте событие `onTouch` с флагами для отслеживания какая кнопка в данный момент "нажата"

Comment: @Jarvis_J, суть в том, что в одну секунду (условно) обрабатывается лишь одно нажатие любой клавиши. Грубо говоря, если 2-мя пальцами тыкнуть одновременно на две кнопки - сработает "нажатие" лишь одной

Comment: `onClick` так и работает. А вы сделайте `onTouch` с отслеживанием `action` `DOWN` и `UP`, который будет запускать функцию, где будут отслеживаться нажатые в настоящий момент кнопки и в зависимости от этого исполнять код